# Oracle : How to reclaim space from table WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$?

Tags: oracle

We are running Oracle 18c.

We deleted thousands of rows from the table **FLOWS_FILES.WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$** with an equivalent of 3 GB of space.

We tried to shrink the space previously used as follows :

```
ALTER TABLE FLOWS_FILES.WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$ MODIFY LOB (BLOB_CONTENT) (SHRINK SPACE);
```

But we are getting the error :

```
ORA-10635: Invalid segment or tablespace type
10635. 00000 -  "Invalid segment or tablespace type"
*Cause:    Cannot shrink the segment because it is not in auto segment space
           managed tablespace or it is not a data, index or lob segment.
*Action:   Check the tablespace and segment type and reissue the statement
```

FLOWS_FILES.WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$ is in table space SYSAUX.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: You will get a more profound answer after moving to the [DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Looks like somebody installed Oracle APEX with a default tablespace (`SYSAUX`) for APEX' schema.  A bad idea; your issue is one of several that can happen.  Quick fix: move that table to an application tablespace  with proper space management.  Better fix: hunt down whoever installed APEX and have them fix it.